# Property value prints but when assigned to label it shows nil

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, properties, null

Currently working with two view controllers and a swift file dealing with the details of a store such as the phone number. There is a main ViewController and a DetailsViewController.

I currently acquire data from google places api and am able to successfully store the values in a PlaceDetails Class. Testing out the data - I am able to print to the console. However, when I try to assign a value taken from the API to a UILabel the application crashes and shows that the value of the property is nil. I am not sure why this is the case. I feel in the two view controllers I am instantiating the PlaceDetails class correctly and accessing it's properties correctly but there is something I am not aware of that is going wrong.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
   let placeDetails = PlaceDetails()
   let detailsVC = DetailsViewController()

   func tapLabel( sender: UITapGestureRecognizer )
   {

    // print statement successfully prints out the stored value as - Optional("1 888-555-5555")
    print(placeDetails.phoneNumber)

    // assigning value to label causes a crash stating value is nil
    detailsVC.phoneNumberLabel.text = placeDetails.phoneNumber!

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailsVC", sender: self)

   }
}

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberLabel  : UILabel!

    let placeDetails = PlaceDetails()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       //This approach does not cause a crash but outputs nil to the console for both the print statement and the assignment statement
       print(placeDetails.phoneNumber)
       phoneNumberLabel.text = placeDetails.phoneNumber! 
    }  
}

class PlaceDetails
{
     override init()
     {
         super.init()
     }
     var phoneNumber : String? //viewcontroller actions give this class property its value
}
```

Comment: is phoneNumberLabel hooked up to the xib?

Comment: @john elemans phoneNumberLabel is all connected as a UILabel on the DetailsViewController on the storyboard :)

Comment: yes, but is in linked to your class variable? in IB if you right click on the UILabel, does it show up under Referencing Outlets as linked or not?

Comment: @johnelemans Yes, it is currently showing as connected in the Referencing Outlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `placeDetails` to your destination view controller in `prepareForSegue`. I know you aren't doing this as you have created `placeDetails` as a `let` constant rather than a variable so it can't ever change from the empty `PlaceDetails` you originally assign.

You should declare it as an optional variable and then unwrap it properly when you use it;

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    let placeDetails = PlaceDetails()

    func tapLabel( sender: UITapGestureRecognizer )
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailsVC", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "showDetailsVC") {
            let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
            destVC.placeDetails = self.placeDetails
        }
    }
}

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberLabel  : UILabel!

    var placeDetails: PlaceDetails?

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let placeDetails = self.placeDetails {
            if let phoneNumber = placeDetails.phoneNumber {
                self.phoneNumberLabel.text = phoneNumber
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can't use the value in `viewDidLoad` as this method will execute before the property has been set; the view controller is loaded before `prepareForSegue` is called, so `viewWillAppear` is a better place.

Comment: Not sure who down voted the answers but yours worked flawlessly and thank you for the lesson! Definitely a major lesson learned going forward :D

Comment: Yeah, not sure either.  Thanks. You definitely need to be careful with using ! - don't just add them to keep the compiler happy; you need to understand when an optional may be nil and test for it

Answer (score -1):

Try to cast your phoneNumber in a string.

```
detailsVC.phoneNumberLabel.text = String(placeDetails.phoneNumber!)
```

Also, the nil value could come from the encoding method of the response of the API.

EDIT

I think you have to set the text of your `UILabel` in the `viewDidLoad()` method of your `showDetailsVC`. Declare a `string` variable in `showDetailVC`, and then pass your `placeDetails.phoneNumber` variable to the string you just declare. (Instead of directly set the text in the `tapLabel()` method). Then in your 
showDetailVC set the text to your UILabel in the `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: just attempted this approach and the issue still occurrs. EXC Bad Instruction and the console displays" fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)"

Comment: just attempted creating a function - func setLabel() { let phoneNumber = placeDetails.phoneNumber     phoneNumberLabel.text = phoneNumber} inside the DetailsViewController and tried calling setLabel() in the viewDidLoad of that class. However the phoneNumber property outputs a "nil" value. This is where I am stuck. Not sure why in one case I can output the phone number correctly but can access the placeDetails property only in that one other case in the ViewController Class.

Comment: it's because you didn't set your placeDetail variable  in the `tapMethod()`  from your first `ViewController` to your `placeDetail` variable to your `DetailViewController ` right ?